# Secure page except for crawlers

Tags: php, html, web-crawler

I am trying to find out how I can restrict access to a certain page except for Social Media crawlers and Google crawler.

That's because even if there is no authenticated user, it would be nice that my links on social media show the meta preview (title, description, image).

---

Creating an exception for these requests I guess it would be a good idea.

I searched online if these crawlers are using another HTTP requests so I can whitelist them. But it seems not, as far as I know.

.htaccess I found out can create exceptions for redirecting. But my authentication gateway is in PHP. And more than that, I would like to pass only the <head> data for these crawlers, so the rest of the page is still protected against the unauthenticated users.

**Question:** Which would be the possibilities? I couldn't find online not even one.

Comment: Alternatively, could you just include the meta tags regardless of who accesses it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a trivial problem - just configure your webserver to allow access by user-agent. There are lots of lists of search engine user-agents available online - usually people are trying to prevent them from accessing content. You should also read up on how to configure a robots.txt to direct bots to the pages and to avoid excluding them.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. I will use user-agent to check if it's a Social Media crawler.